# Google script triggers authentication

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created `trigger` programmatically on the user's profile. It's working as required since couple of months.

Last week I have changed the code of trigger program and published. But still, users are getting authentication pop up.

Do I need to programmatically delete the existing trigger of all users profile and create again?

Or any other option could you suggest

Comment: If your function needs authorization to run, then users have to authorize it. If it needs to modify your resources as well, those will have to be editable by the users of your add-on

Comment: Yes, function modified by me needed authorization and for same function trigger have been created for users. But I cannot ask all users to manually go to script Editor and save. Do we have any other options

Comment: have you looked at any documentation about add on? Obtaining authorization / launching authorization flow is a part of the install / on open simple trigger responsibility. In other words, add a menu option for the case where the user has not authorized the script, and in that menu provide a function to call. When the user attempts to run the function, they will be prompted to authorize your script.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Yes, I know the authorization will required by users on trigger function changes. But manually for all users will it be good or any other way to approach

Comment: every user must manually complete the authorization flow - **you cannot run functions with their data without their explicit approval**. What you can do is reduce the effort needed to authorize, by providing them with a menu option, rather than making them open the Script Editor.